# Flex layout in firefox collapsed until window is resized

Tags: css, reactjs, firefox, flexbox

The images probably explains the problem better then words:

This is how it should look like, works in Chrome:
[image: Correct]
This is how it looks like in Firefox:
[image: Wrong]

Basically the problem is, that the first two columns collapse to zero width.

Once I resize the window by any small amount or make any live changes to the CSS, it fixes itself, but the initial load always looks like this.

The code:

App.js, using react and react-bootstrap

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Container fluid className={styles.app} >
      <Row className={styles.layoutRow + " h-100 m-0"}>
        <Col md="auto" className={styles.col + " d-flex text-center"}>
          <Name />
        </Col>
        <Col md="auto" className={styles.col + " d-flex"}>
          <Menu />
        </Col>
        <Col className={styles.col}>
          <Content/>
        </Col>
      </Row>

    </Container>
  );
}
```

CSS (applied via the styles.app / styles.col)

```
.app, .col {
    padding-left: 1vh !important;
    padding-right: 1vh !important;
}
```

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-dawn-mryny

Comment: Could you please setup a codesandbox to reproduce the problem

Comment: I added a link to it.